# Is there a way to de-orphan users without setting context to a restored database?

Tags: sql-server, security

I have an installation script that restores a database from a template.bak file and then makes a few alterations. This question flows on from another question: [How do I create databases / logins / users with minimal privileges when installing an application?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169404/how-do-i-create-databases-logins-users-with-minimal-privileges-when-installi).

Prior to running the installation, a script is executed that creates two SQL Login accounts MyAdmin and MyUser with what I believe is the necessary privileges (MyAdmin is used by the installer and a server management application, MyUser is used by the client application):

```
create login MyAdmin with password = 'TemporaryPassword'
exec sp_addsrvrolemember 'MyAdmin', 'diskadmin'
grant create any database to MyAdmin
grant alter any database to MyAdmin
create login MyUser with password = 'TemporaryPassword'
```

In the installation script I connect with the MyAdmin account and restore the template.bak file. I can see that the database is created and MyAdmin is the owner of the database. However:
- the instruction `use MyNewDatabase` fails with `The server principal "MyAdmin" is not able to access the database "MyNewDatabase" under the current security context.`
- if I login as sa in my test environment, I can see that the dbo user in the database has a user type 'SQL user without login'.

This leaves me very surprised. How is that the MyAdmin user can create a database, but cannot use it? Why is the dbo user not assigned to the owner / creator of the database?

The advice I have read so far is to use `alter user MyAdmin ...`, however I need to switch context to the database `use MyNewDatabase` to accomplish this - which I cannot do while the login is not linked to the user - a very frustrating catch-22.

I have found that I can resolve the issue by performing all of these tasks with the SA account, however I will not have access to the SA account with the installer as this is a commercial application.

Is there a way to de-orphan the accounts without setting context to MyNewDatabase?

Comment: It might be possible if I change the create login script to set a SID - the same SID as the one in my original template database. I will look into this tomorrow (I'm in Australia - so it's nearly 5pm here).

Answer (score 1):

When creating the login principals, set the SID of the login to the original login.

Original server `select name, sid from templatedb.sys.database_principals` to get the SID

New server `create login MyAdmin with password = 'DummyPassword951', sid = 0xBCB4D3AC87D6F449979D6810B8E9E250`

Edit: FYI MyAdmin is the owner of the template database and is mapped to the dbo user. In the installed version of the database, I have mapped the MyAdmin login to the dbo user, using the dbo SID from the template DB.

Comment: Note that `MyAdmin` is the database owner after the restore. Although the explicit SID will correctly map the `MyAdmin` to the `MyAdmin` user, the SID for the restored database `dbo` user will be wrong because a login can be mapped to only one database user.

Comment: I have heard that it is better to have the SA account be the owner of all databases, which is not something I can enforce in the template database. What I should do is:

- in the template database make SA the owner, create a MyAdmin user and map the MyAdmin login to the MyAdmin user.
- in the destination server create an ApplicationInstaller account and restore the database with that, ensuring that MyAdmin is mapped to the new MyAdmin user SID.

This way, the DBA can make SA the owner of the database and it will still work.

Comment: Actually, making SA the owner of all databases is a common practice (and it is convenient from a restoration point of view), but this blog provides reasons why that would be a bad idea from a security perpsective: http://www.insidesql.org/blogs/andreaswolter/2014/06/sql-server-database-ownership-survey-results-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

It seems the backup of the template database was taken with a user named `MyAdmin` in the database, resulting in the orphaned user after the restore. As the database owner following the restore, `MyAdmin` should not have a user account in the database because `MyAdmin` is implicitly mapped to the `dbo` user in the restored database.

I suggest you drop the `MyAdmin` user from the template database and take another backup. You will then be able to use the restored database as the `MyAdmin` login with the `dbo` user context. Under that context, you can execute `ALTER USER MyUser;` to fix the mapping for the non-dbo user.